# How to change a Library R.ids

Tags: android, r.java-file

Hey guys I wish to use a Library im my app but want to change the default id codes for example it will generate R.java file with an id for say:

public static int ic_launcher as 0x7f020000;

but want it to be 0x6f020000 any ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

the R.java is an auto generated file ...and you should not modify...whatsoever

it is written at the top of the file

```
    /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
```

Comment: I don't want to modify it I want the auto generated ids to be generated differently.

Answer (score 0):

The Library R.ids, It is generates R.id automatically in R.java when creating id in XMLs file.
We could not change in R.java.

If change anything in xmls or string.xml then automatically reflect in R.java.

means public static int ic_launcher as 0x7f020000; remains same.

Please dont try to change in R.java, according to my knowledge

Comment: I understand but this can be done somehow I have an example of it here on my desktop. I just can figure out how.

Comment: @user2655267 u could not changes in R.java. It is autogenerated